# How is the Variance of this estimator equal to $\theta$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Currently going through solutions of a worksheet and I don't understand the jump between two lines of working.

"$\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\hat{\theta}_2$ are independent unbiased estimators for an unknown parameter $\theta$, with respective variances ${\sigma}_1^2$ and ${\sigma}_2^2$. Show that $\hat{\theta}_3 = \lambda\hat{\theta}_1 + (1 − \lambda)\hat{\theta}_2$ is also an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ for all values of $\lambda$"

This is straightforward and gave me no problems, I have included it in case it is relevant for the next part

"Calculate the variance of $\hat{\theta}_3$"

The solution given is

Var[$\hat{\theta}_3$] $= {\lambda}^2$Var[$\hat{\theta}_1$]$+(1−λ)^2$Var[$\hat{\theta}_2$]

$= {\lambda}^2{\sigma}^2_1+ {(1 − \lambda)}^2{\sigma}^2_2$

$= \theta$

The part which I don't understand is how ${\lambda}^2{\sigma}^2_1+ {(1 − \lambda)}^2{\sigma}^2_2 = \theta$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks very strange. I doubt that equality really holds, there may be a typo or something.

Comment: Are any other details given about the distributions involved?  Maybe the author suddenly thought he was calculating the mean and not the variance.

Comment: Something must be wrong. If e.g. $\theta<0$ then it cannot equalize a variance.

Comment: To show the unbiasedness, you actually don't need the information about the variance.

Comment: @Zhanxiong That was just the first part of the question which he added just in case necessary information was provided there. His question is about calculating $\mathbb{Var}[\hat{\theta}_3]$.

Comment: @molarmass I overlooked it. I am pretty sure it is a typo, leave $\lambda^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1 - \lambda)^2 \sigma_2^2$ would be fine.

Comment: I've messaged the lecturer to clarify, thanks anyhow